# How to add a timer in MessageBox.Show()?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

as the title says, I know MessageBox.Show has the features of adding in character text, I was wondering if there is a code to add the system's time in the MessageBox.Show? Like:

```
MessageBox.Show("Hello, today's date is: " & time.now)
```

I know this code with the time is weird so just hoping if someone knows how to add the current time of the system user's computer?

Comment: Yea I thought the vba would be related to Visual Basic programming language

Comment: Looks like your asking how to put *the time* into a message box, not *a timer*.  Those are very different things.  Your subject made me think you wanted to be able to show a message box for a certain duration and then, presumably, automatically dismiss it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do it simply, just use this:

```
MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

Or, in your case:

```
MessageBox.Show("Hello, today's date is: " + DateTime.Now.ToString(), "Attention!", 
   MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

The [MessageBox Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is overloaded with just about anything and everything you could want; and if it doesn't have it, you can always just make your own.

Answer (score 4):

That looks like VB syntax. If you want to show the date in your message using C# syntax, use this:

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Concat("Hello, today's date is: ", DateTime.Now);
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean

```
MessageBox.Show( "Hello, today's date is: " + DateTime.Now.toString);?
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MessageBox.Show("Hello, today's date is: " & DateTime.Now.ToString())
```